# Pachyderm pipeline unable to pull docker image

Tags: docker, pachyderm

I have successfully pushed my docker image to the registry:
`my-username/image-name`

However, pachyderm is still unable to pull docker image(from logs):

```
container "user" in pod "pipeline-mopng-beneficiary-v2-v1-b6kln" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

Where should I specify the image so that pachyderm is able to pull one?
This is my config file:

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "mopng-beneficiary-v2"
    },
    "input": {
        "pfs": {
            "repo": "mopng_beneficiary_v2",
            "glob": "/*"
        }
    },
    "transform": {
        "cmd": ["python3", "/pclean.py /pfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/euoEQHIwIQTe1wXtg46fFYok.csv /pfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2//Users/aviralsrivastava/Downloads/5Feb18_master_ujjwala_latlong_dist_dno_so_v7.csv /pfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2//Users/aviralsrivastava/Downloads/ppac_master_v3_mmi_enriched_with_sanity_check.csv /pfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/Qc.csv"],
        "image": "username/my-image"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is pachyderm running? Is it in minikube, GKE, AWS? The error above seems to point to a networking issue. Meaning that `docker pull  username/my-image` can't get to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be missing [`image_pull_secrets: []`](https://github.com/pachyderm/pachyderm/blame/v1.8.4/doc/reference/pipeline_spec.md#L31) (documented [further down in the spec](https://github.com/pachyderm/pachyderm/blame/v1.8.4/doc/reference/pipeline_spec.md#L228-L239))